# Add page number on every page of \documentclass{book}

Tags: page-numbering, books, documentclass

How do I force there to be a page number on *every* page of a `\documentclass{book}` document, including on the title page and the blank pages before `\part{}`s?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\raggedbottom
\sloppy
\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\part*{First Part} 

\chapter*{First Chap}

stuff

\end{document}
```

produces output with no page number on the first PDF page and no page number on the blank page before the "First Chap" chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can redefine style `empty` used on blank pages.

Please see the following code (I added package `showframe` to visualize the typing area and margins):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{showframe} % <==============================================
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{empty}{% <==============================================
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\raggedbottom
\pagestyle{plain}

\sloppy
\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\date{}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\part*{First Part} 

\chapter*{First Chap}

stuff

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

The title page:

[image]